# How to use custom icons on a leaflet-omnivore layer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to change the default marker for one of my KML layers. I'm using leaflet-omnivore for this.

This is the code I already have. The markers are not changing to the image and the layer control is only displaying the text, even though the img bit is in the code.

Marker Code:

```
var redIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'icon.png',
    iconSize:     [20, 24],
    iconAnchor:   [12, 55], 
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] 
});

var nissanLayer = omnivore.kml('icons.kml')
    .on('ready', function() {
        map.fitBounds(customLayer.getBounds());
         //change the icons for each point on the map
         // After the 'ready' event fires, the GeoJSON contents are accessible
        // and you can iterate through layers to bind custom popups.
        customLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            // See the `.bindPopup` documentation for full details. This
            // dataset has a property called `name`: your dataset might not,
            // so inspect it and customize to taste.
            layer.icon
            layer.bindPopup('<img src="icon.png" height="24"><br><h3>'+layer.feature.properties.name+'</h3>');
        });
    })
.addTo(map);


  var marker = new L.Marker(customLayer, {icon:redIcon});
      map.addLayer(marker);
```

Comment: Is `custonIcon1` a typo in your original code or a copy/paste error here?

Comment: it was a typo here.

Comment: @peeebeee any help?

Answer (score 6):

You seem to have overlooked the [`setIcon()` method of `L.Marker`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#marker-seticon). I'd also check that a `L.Layer` is in fact a `L.Marker` before calling any `L.Marker` functionality, just for code sanity. e.g.:

```
var redIcon = L.icon({ /* ... */ });

var omnivoreLayer = omnivore.kml('icons.kml')
    .on('ready', function() {
        omnivoreLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {

            if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
                layer.setIcon(redIcon);
            }
        });
    })
    .addTo(map);
```

However, the [Leaflet-Omnivore documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#custom-layers) says that the better way to apply custom styling to an Omnivore layer is to create a `L.GeoJSON` instance with the desired filters and styling, and then pass that to the Omnivore factory method. I suggest you read the [Leaflet tutorial on GeoJSON](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) to become familiar with this.

So instead of relying on a `on('ready')` event handler (which would *change* the markers after they are created), this would save a tiny bit of time by creating the markers directly with the desired style:

```
var omnivoreStyleHelper = L.geoJSON(null, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: redIcon});
    }
});

var omnivoreLayer = omnivore.kml('icons.kml', null, omnivoreStyleHelper);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used leaflet that much but I did a small project where I set the icons to an image.

```
var redIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'red-x.png',

   iconSize:     [25, 25], // size of the icon
   iconAnchor:   [12, 55], // point of the icon which will correspond to 
   marker's location
   popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open 
   relative to the iconAnchor
});


  var marker = new L.Marker(markerLocation, {icon:redIcon});
      mymap.addLayer(marker);
```

Not sure how helpful this is really.

Links got a guide to follow which might be more use https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

Comment: I have added the code and it isnt working - Cannot read property 'lat' of null.  Please see my updated original question with all the code im using.

Comment: Did you fix your issue @Jason